# Windows 7 pipes and Symlink - com port

Tags: cmd, windows-7, serial-port, pipe, symlink

That's the situation: I've a program that sends data to a text file. Those are just information about lights state of an arcade machine. I need to send this information on a COM port, so I've replaced the txt file with a symbolic link to a pipe. I don't have access to the source code of this main program. The only way I've found to do that in Windows 10 is creating a symbolic link using pipes like this:

```
mklink SymlinkName \\.\pipe\pipename
```

Then I've create a program that reads the pipe and sends it to the COM port. It works fine on Windows 10 without any kind of problem and I've worked on that OS for my development.

Today I've tried all this stuff on the arcade machine (windows 7 Ultimate based) but the Symlink doesn't work. I can send data to my COM port simpy using command line, for example

```
echo foo > COM1
```

But if I try to do that throught the Symlink, it sais:

```
echo foo > Symlink
The data present in the reparse point buffer is invalid.
```

Any suggestion? I've already tried to Google it but no luck!